# asana api - assign tag to task via api

Tags: asana

I'm creating a new task in [Asana - Task Management for Teams](http://www.asana.com/) via the API. Is there a way to **assign a tag to a task** via the API? Would be really helpful in terms of filtering.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a well written Asana API documentation. Lookup for [Task][2] AND [Tags](http://developer.asana.com/api-updates/) API listing :)
Good luck with that.

---

**Update:**
This is another [filtered Asana Tag result](http://developer.asana.com/api-updates/) for you.

It says:

```
The task endpoint now has addTag and removeTag methods.
```